# ImageMagick - How to change saturation of a targeted color?

Tags: image, colors, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

With ImageMagick convert, how to adjust the saturation of a specific hue of colors? (in degrees)

e.g. I increase the saturation of the red (0 degree hue). The bluish colors will not be affected, but the orange will be saturated a little bit as well since it is next to the red.

Of course I'd like to be able to configure the width of colors affected.

NOTE: please use convert commands, not redirect to a script.

PS: to clarify after **emcconville**'s answer:

The saturation would be progressive: the closer we are to the matching color, the more the filter applies. Basically the way it is done in Photoshop. See screenshot - sorry it's in french, Teinte means Hue. You can see and adjust the range of matching color in degrees in the bottom bar, between 8 and 90 (and 318 to 255) the filter is progressive.

[image: Photoshop Saturation Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Color Modification](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#color_mods) guide offers a few examples

Here's an example that will drop the saturation by half if the hue is close to red (0°)

```
convert rose: \( +clone -modulate 100,50 \) \
        -fx '(u.hue < 0.1 || u.hue > 0.9)? v : u' out.png
```

[image: Change saturation of a targeted color]

This works by copying the first image ([`+clone`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clone)), and alter the saturation ([`-modulate`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#modulate)) of the copied image. For the [`-fx`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fx) part, `u` is the first image, and `v` is the second. If the `hue` of the first image matches our color, return the second image, else return the first.

> Note: Red is 0°, so we need a logical OR (`||`), but if we're attempting to match another color, *not overlapping zero,* use the logical AND (`&&`).
>
> *example with blue*
>
> ```
> -fx '(u.hue < 0.69 && u.hue > 0.63) ? v : u'
> ```

### Additional Answer

The same `-fx` approach can be used by calculating the *linear* scale -- like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43698/range-scaling-problem/43699#43699), or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224103002/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60433.html). Below is a similar (but not accurate) equation, and shows how to isolate the *saturation* channel.

```
convert rose: -colorspace HSL \
  \( +clone -colorspace sRGB \
     -fx '(hue < 0.1)?saturation+((1-(hue+0.1)*10%1)/10):(hue > 0.9)?saturation+(((hue-0.1) * 10)%1):saturation-(abs(0.5-hue))' \
  \) \
  -compose CopyGreen -composite \
  -colorspace sRGB \
  out.png
```

[image: More change saturation of a targeted color]

The `-compose CopyGreen -composite` seems odd, but what that is really doing is taking the image generated with `-fx`, and applying that as the second color channel (saturation).

Also experiment with [`-color-matrix`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#color-matrix), [`-contrast-stretch`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#contrast-stretch), & [`-linear-stretch`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#linear-stretch).

Comment: @FlorianB: If the answer taught you something great, you can still 'upvote' it. Additionally 'accept' it (or another one), once it is modified/amended to solve your problem completely.